# JQuery mobile listview filter initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to programmatically initialize the value of the filter box of a listview?

Comment: I tried, its not working. http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/MZHXU/

Comment: with jQM 1.4 you can using `filterable` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to trigger the 'change' event after the input was changed.

Seems like normal key input automatically triggers 'change' events but not simulated key inputs.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/MZHXU/20/

I only added the line

```
$("[data-type=search]").trigger("change");
```

and it works fine.